# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, getter-setter

```
class Account :
def __init__(self, firstName, id, cash):
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.id = id
    self.cash = cash
    
    @property
    def get_cash(self, cash):
        return self._cash
    
    @cash.setter
    def set_cash(self, cash):
        if (cash < 0):
            print("Seu saldo parece negativo, gostaria de contratar um serviço de empréstimo ou crédito?")
        
        else:
            self._cash = cash
```

File "c:\...Account.py", line 11, in **init**
@cash.setter
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setter'

Comment: Fix the indentation first.

Answer (score 1):

So your issue is here at line 8. Instead of naming it "get_cash", you should name it "cash", because it is directly under the @property decorator, iirc. So it should be then like this:

```
@property
def cash(self, cash):
    return self._cash
```

Also, on line 12, the function should then be called "cash", like this:

```
@cash.setter
def cash(self, cash):
    if (cash < 0):
        print("Seu saldo parece negativo, gostaria de contratar um serviço de empréstimo ou crédito?")       
    else:
        self._cash = cash
```

Because of this, you should rename your cash variable in the init (just for clarification purposes/readability).
For more info you can look at: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-property-decorator/